# Is there a tool that generates my parts database?

Tags: sets

I have many LEGO sets (mostly Technic) and I would like to build a list of parts (including colours). Is there an online service that does that for me based on the set IDs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both BrickLink and Brickset maintains a database. Brickset pulls data directly from LEGO's servers, which means the data is not always accurate for older sets or brand new sets (when the parts are not uploaded to LEGO's servers yet). BrickLink's parts list is maintained and meticulously verified by volunteers, and it is the most accurate of all LEGO databases. This includes both old and new sets.

Go to BrickLink.com, click "Sets" on the Homepage, and type in the set number you are looking for. Click on "Item Consist Of", and it will give you a list of all the parts in the set, including parts names, IDs, colors, year of release, weight, etc.

While BrickLink is the largest online LEGO marketplace, and it is mainly meant for buying and selling LEGO, you can also use it as a database for the sets and parts you own. This is very useful if you have a large collection, and can come in handy for evaluation and insurance purposes, or if you ever decide to sell your collection (or parts of).

Brickset is also great for maintaining a database of your collection, but as mentioned above, it is not the most reliable as far as parts lists. The focus is mostly on collectors being able to catalogue the sets they own. In addition, Brickset gives you a full value of your collection based on original retail price (vs. the current market prices given by BrickLink), and has some other useful tools. I recommend using both sites, but if you only want to use one, I would suggest BrickLink. It will give you everything you need to catalog the parts you have.

Comment: I would also mention BrickStock (brickstock.patrickbrans.com) which is an application you install locally on your computer to manage BrickLink inventories. It allows you to save your sets and part them out on your local computer, and merge all inventories into one large inventory to manage as a whole. For this purpose the program is free of charge (seller features require a $20 license key)

Comment: On Bricklink I can only list the parts relating to the particular set i've chosen one by one. Is it possible to define my list of sets as my "inventory" and do queries to check how many pieces of a specific item do i have? I can only add sets to my account as items for sale. Am I missing something?

Comment: To use BL for cataloguing your parts, you will need to register as a seller, but keep your store closed (it doesn't cost anything to register as a seller). You could part out the sets you own in Stockroom A, but make sure the store remains closed, as Stockroom A is the default for running a store. You don't want to have your store open if you are only managing your personal inventory. Or you could just put everything in Stockroom B or C to begin with, as these are hidden. It's very easy to move items from stockroom to stockroom in case you want to sell something in the future.

Comment: Re-reading your question, I may have read it wrong the first time around. If you want to add parts from the set to your inventory, you will need to hit the "Part Out" link below the "Add to My Inventory" link. That will allow you to part out the set, rather than add it as a whole set.

Comment: I've managed to create the database with the "part out" option. However, I noticed that parts of different sets are stored in different groups even if they have the same part number. So now I have 21 groups for the pin with part number 2780, just because I uploaded 21 sets. Is there a way to collapse all these separated groups?

Comment: It appears that you added the parts to your inventory from different sets into separate lots instead of consolidating them whenever you added a new parted out set. You can read about consolidating lots here:  https://www.bricklink.com/help.asp?helpID=128